# Match() and the dynamic selection of columns of a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to use the `match()` function when dynamically selecting a column from a data.table `DT1` while applying a filter and matching it to the column of another data.table `DT2`. It doesn't work, presumably because when one selects a column dynamically from a data.table, the output is again a data.table rather than a vector.

An example:

```
col1 = c(1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2)
col2 = c("Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Asia", "Asia")
DT1 = data.table(col1, col2)

col3 = 1:3
col4 = c( "carrot", "apple", "tomato")
DT2 = data.table(col3, col4)
```

This works:

```
> match(DT1[col2 == "Europe", col1], DT2[, col3])
[1] 1 3 1 3
```

This (what I need) doesn't work:

```
> columnName = "col1"
> match(DT1[col2 == "Europe", columnName, with = FALSE], DT2[, col3])
[1] NA
```

Only when col1 is entered as a variable in `j` of a data.table, the result is a vector. Could this be the reason? To illustrate what I mean:

```
> DT1[, col1]
[1] 1 3 1 3 2 2
> DT1[, "col1"]
   col1
1:    1
2:    3
3:    1
4:    3
5:    2
6:    2
```

I thought `match()` would deal with this automatically because itshelp file states:

*"Factors, raw vectors and lists are converted to character vectors, and then x and table are coerced to a common type (the later of the two types in R's ordering, logical < integer < numeric < complex < character) before matching. If incomparables has positive length it is coerced to the common type."*

Comment: You can try subsetting with `[[`, i.e. `match(DT1[col2 == "Europe"][[columnName]], DT2[, col3])`

Comment: @docendodiscimus that works thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@docendodiscimus provided a solution for data tables: *the answerYou can try subsetting with [[, i.e. match(DT1[col2 == "Europe"][[columnName]], DT2[, col3])*

Answer (score 1):

It seems to work when not using data.table, I think you should be careful when using `col1` because there is confusion between the vector `col1` and the column of the data.frame or data.table.

```
DT1 = data.frame(col1=c(1, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2), col2=c("Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Europe", "Asia", "Asia"))
DT2 = data.frame(col3 = 1:3, col4 = c( "carrot", "apple", "tomato"))

match(DT1[DT1$col2 == "Europe", "col1"], DT2[, "col3"])

columnName = "col1"
match(DT1[DT1$col2 == "Europe", columnName], DT2[, "col3"])
```

Comment: with data frames it works indeed. I was actually trying to convert my working data frame code:) I don't want to use data frame anymore because I find data table faster and the code easier to read.